# What is Static caching of intermediate JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am new to Node.js and EJS. "Static Caching of Intermediate JavaScript" is mentioned as one of the features of EJS.Can anybody explain what it exactly means.

Regards,
Kar

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a template, like so:

```
<h1><%= name %></h1>
```

Internally, this will compile to something along these lines (very simplified):

```
function(params) {
    return '<h1>' + params.name + '</h1>';
}
```

That javascript function is really fast to execute, compared to parsing the template over and over again. EJS will *cache* the function internally, if you call it with the `cache` option. Thus, it will not have to compile the template each time it is rendered.